# Read .csv file from AWS S3 - Forbidden

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to read .csv file from AWS S3, but I got Forbidden message, I already set full access to everyone (just for this case).. but still no luck..

what I missed?

anybody have experience on this?

```
import boto3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import xgboost as xgb

# Defining utility methods
# Reference: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html
# bucket: Name of bucket
# key: File name stored in S3

def write_to_s3(filename, bucket, key):
    with open(filename,'rb') as f: # Read in binary mode
        return boto3.Session().resource('s3').Bucket(bucket).Object(key).upload_fileobj(f)


def download_from_s3(filename, bucket, key):
    with open(filename,'wb') as f:
        return boto3.Session().resource('s3').Bucket(bucket).Object(key).download_fileobj(f)


# Downloading file from S3
download_from_s3('mypredictive.csv', 'my-bucket-004', 'mypredictive.csv')

# Reading CSV File
df = pd.read_csv('mypredictive.csv')

# Let's see how our data looks like
df.head(2)
```

====

```
  ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    659             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    660             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 661             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    662         else:
    663             return parsed_response

ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

Comment: I think your problem is regarding ACL. You should read about on S3 ACL. Go to this link which solves the same problem.
http://www.stojanveselinovski.com/blog/2016/05/20/aws-s3-object-acl-and-403-error/

Answer (score 0):

just want to share:

this error is caused by SageMaker service role (The role that I use to create SageMaker notebook) not having permission to your specific s3 bucket, to grant SageMaker service role access your bucket, you could add bellow policy to your SageMaker service role ( AmazonSageMaker-ExcutionRole by default):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "kms:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

cheers!

Comment: You are providing the ability to Delete objects from every single S3 bucket.